# What is the difference between tbl function and data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am beginning my study of dplyr and the first thing it is explained in [this RStudio tutorial](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/219545_47274c811c464f1ca1f07959b8243688.html) is about TBL's. The page doesn't explain what is it, only says "it is a special type of data frame".

What is the difference between them?

Comment: Run `library(tibble); ?tibble` and read on, it explains the differences.

Comment: ...although, oddly, that documentation really *should* mention that `tbl[,1]` doesn't drop dimensions like `df[,1]` will.

Comment: Looks like it's mentioned in `help("tibble-package")`, but it should probably be mentioned both places, tbh.

Comment: Hadley explained here as well http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> mt <- matrix(sample(1:25), nc = 5)
> data.frame(mt)
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 16  7 14 19 25
2 11 23 24 15  3
3  4  9 21  8 12
4 18 20  1 22  2
5 13  5 17  6 10
> as_tibble(mt)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    16     7    14    19    25
2    11    23    24    15     3
3     4     9    21     8    12
4    18    20     1    22     2
5    13     5    17     6    10
```

`tibble` will show only first few rows and columns, as well as provides the infomration of `nrow` and `ncol`, vector `class` type of every single column to fit the windows where `data.frame` won't.